# ORA-29273: HTTP request failed ORA-29259: end-of-input reached ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_HTTP", line 1491

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c, utl-http

i am getting the following error ORA-29273: HTTP request failed ORA-29259: end-of-input reached ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_HTTP", line 1491 when running this query
SELECT  utl_http.request('http://www.$$$$.org/xxxxxx/WorkflowServer?action=run_proc&user=xxx&password=xxxxxxxx&schema=Download') FROM   dual;

Database version Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production